# 'gmaps4rails' undefined local variable or method 'acts_as_gmappable' rails 3.2.1 routing error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, gmaps4rails

just playing around with the gem 'gmaps4rails' but I'm getting the following routing error

```
undefined local variable or method `acts_as_gmappable'
```

I've performed the following steps:
1) added the following to the Gemfile: gem 'gmaps4rails' and bundled
2) generated scaffold Location
3) added the following to my model, location.rb then db:migrate

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :address, :latitude, :longitude
  acts_as_gmappable

  def gmaps4rails_address
    address
  end
end
```

5) changed my root to the following and deleted the old index file

```
root :to => 'locations#index'
```

6) added the following to  the body of aplication.html.erb

```
<%= yield :scripts %>
```

Seems like it can't find the methods in the gem I installed?

I'm using gmaps4rails v2.0.3, ruby v1.9.3, rails 3.2.1

I've looked on similar topics on stackoverflow and performed simple tasks such as restarting server etc but still the same error.

@apneadiving maybe you could help?

Many thanks

Comment: use `Zeus` or `Spring`?

Comment: V2 doesnt provide acts_as_gmappable anymore, read doc on github

Comment: Use geocoder for geocoding, gmaps4rails to display maps

Comment: I've made a video tutorial, link provided on github's repo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the Docs of gmaps4rails, since 2.* version you don't have to add the acts_as_gmappable method.
Now it uses geocoder.
Here is an small [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R0l-7en3dUw&feature=youtu.be), that explains how it works.